# Vulkan video backend on Intel graphics card/mesa driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, mesa, vulkan

I saw in Dolphin emulator that Vulkan was a video backend option, like OpenGL, I use an Intel graphics card with Mesa driver that came with my Ubuntu install. How do I check my Vulkan version, and install it if it's not there? I'm on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

You can check your Vulkan version by installing *vulkan-utils* and running `vulkaninfo`. You can install Vulkan drivers by installing package *mesa-vulkan-drivers*.